# How can I find at only a certain groups of dates within a sorted list in Python?

Tags: python

I have sorted lists of starting times and ending times. I also have a very large sorted list of times, t.

Right now, I am doing the extremely slow:

```
for start, end in zip(startTimes, endTimes):

    for time in t:
 
        if start <= t <= end:
            do something
```

This looks at each element in t every single time. I know I can reduce this by making some elifs for whether or not t < start or end < t, but there must be a way to take advantage of the lists being sorted.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Where does `t` come from in the loop `for time in t` and then in the comparison again `if start <= t <= end`?

Comment: Use binary search? E.g. [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect)

Comment: Do your start / end times overlap?

Comment: If the list is sorted you can 1) find the first and last element -- there is your 'certain range' or 2) use `groupby`

Comment: Something like https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/ is an option as well. Load the intervals defined by `zip(startTimes, endTimes)` into an interval tree, then perform point queries on the times in `t` to find the interval(s), if any, that contain each `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a 1,000,000 day interval in list `t`:

```
import datetime as dt 

st=dt.datetime(1990, 1, 1)
t=[st]
for i in range(1_000_000):
    t.append(t[-1]+dt.timedelta(days=1))

>>> t[-1]
4727-11-29 00:00:00   # if man is still alive...
```

You can use [itertools groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find sub intervals:

```
from itertools import groupby   
x=dt.datetime(2040,2,2)
y=dt.datetime(2040,2,6) 
for k,v in groupby(t, key=lambda d: x<=d<=y):
    if k:
        print(list(v))
```

Prints:

```
[datetime.datetime(2040, 2, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2040, 2, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2040, 2, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2040, 2, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2040, 2, 6, 0, 0)]
```

On my little laptop that is nearly instant.

If you have several intervals, you can use `any` in your `groupby` lambda:

```
from itertools import groupby   

intervals=[(dt.datetime(2020,1,6),dt.datetime(2020,1,8)),
           (dt.datetime(2062,8,27),dt.datetime(2062,8,28)),
           (dt.datetime(3501,1,1),dt.datetime(3501,1,3))]
for k,v in groupby(t, key=lambda x: any(tu[0]<=x<=tu[1] for tu in intervals)):
    if k:
        print(list(v))
```